# Multi-tier professional framework for .NET

Tags: windows, .net, framework

We are planning a refactoring of our accounting application (80+ firms use it or we have a total of roughly 1000 users) to multi-tier, as well as modernizing it (it's written in Delphi VCL).

At first, we found Data Abstract because it worked on Delphi. But now, we are considering using .NET for the middle-tier, and we don't know which technology to use.

We are looking for a full-fledged framework for multi-tier. It should support standard communication protocols (HTTP/HTTPS, ODATA, …) as well as having ready-to-use boilerplate modules, such as authentication, login, etc.

Ideally, it would also have some set of libraries for easy integration on different client platforms (OS X, iOS, Windows, Android, JavaScript).

We found so far

- RemObject's Data Abstract
- WCF

Do anyone know of any other professional solution for this problem?

Comment: Seems like a lot of this is already built into things like Entity Framework and .NET itself, for example a REST Web API. Its difficult to answer though because of the broad interpretation of "multi-tier". .NET itself can do what you are asking, but you'll have to be more specific on requirements to get library recommendations.